# SQL Check if two columns from two tables are completely disjoint

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, full-outer-join, disjoint-sets

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE A
    ID   INT   PRIMARY KEY
    ....

CREATE TABLE B
    ID   INT   PRIMARY KEY
    ....
```

How do I check if `A.ID` and `B.ID` are disjoint using postgres.

- Disjoint meaning there is no value in `B.ID` that exists in `A.ID` and vice versa.
- I want to return a boolean.

Here's an example

```
/* Returns False */
A.ID: 4, 5, 6, 7
B.ID: 5, 7, 8, 9

/* Returns True */
A.ID: 1, 2, 3, 4
B.ID: 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Please define *disjoint*. Sample data and desired results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: Whoops my bad. Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure the tables have no `id` in common, you can do:

```
select bool_and(a.id is distinct from b.id) res
from a
full join b on a.id = b.id
```

This returns a boolean flag that is set to true if the tables have no common `id`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just wondering, is `res` a special keyword? If not, what is it?

Comment: @PatWong: that's just an alias for the column in the resultset, it does not have any special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to solve this problem :

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN (  SELECT
                    COUNT(*) 
                FROM
                    A 
                WHERE
                    ID IN ( SELECT
                                * 
                            FROM
                                B
                    ))>0 
        THEN FALSE 
        ELSE TRUE 
    END
```